# pythonで文字列をインスタンスに変更する方法

Tags: python

pythonで文字列をインスタンスに変更する方法を知りたいです。
例えば、

```
a = 10
string = "a"
```

と宣言されている場合

```
print func(string)
```

で10と出力されるような関数(func)があれば教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

そういう関数は知りませんが、変数の種類が予めわかってるなら辞書を作ればできます。

```
dic={}
dic["a"]=a
```

これで、

```
dic[string] = 10
```

になります。

Answer (score 6):

お勧めしませんが、これでどうでしょう

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec 16 2016, 03:08:23)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = 10
>>> string = 'a'
>>> print locals()[string]
10
```

Answer (score 1):

お勧めしませんが、典型的なevalですね。

```
>>> a=10
>>> eval("a")
10
```